# Is it correct to start a sentence with "Here describes"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In one of the manuals written by an american company I have found several sentences started with "Here describes".
Example: "Here describes common processing method and notices for Task program".
I'm in great doubt, is this correct?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Why not go with 'The following lines/paragraph describe..' or 'Common processing methods and notices for task program are described as follows'?

Comment: _Describe_ requires a subject that does the describing, not one that is the description. You could use the passive -- _Here is described ..._

Comment: If you are still in the earlier stages of learning English, you should take a look at our [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange.

Comment: I suspect the purpose of the construction is (a failed attempt) to avoid the passive voice, which is frowned upon in manuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here* is a locative preposition. We very rarely see prepositions or preposition phrases functioning as Subjects in English. When they do, they are nearly always used with verbs such as *BE* or *SEEM* which take Predicative Complements:

- After Christmas would be best.
- In the corner seems like a good choice.

Generally, the verb *DESCRIBE* semantically requires an animate Subject or a Subject made by somebody animate ( a book, or a film, for example). *Here* does not fulfil this requirement, and is also restricted in its ability to function as a Subject, due to its being a preposition.

Answer (score 3):

**Here** can't describe something, it can't be the subject of an action because it can't do anything.
Hence you would use:

> Here **is/are described** the [...].

instead.

Comment: So be it, I really didn't want to answer+comment, but well.